# What single word (verb) means 'to realize as a moral norm' or 'to bring into being as a moral norm'?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Imagine that the term "grrfumblezig" is a verb, defined as "to realize as a moral norm" or "to bring into being as a moral norm".

An example sentence using this term is: "The architecture of the societal systems within which the ancient Greeks were forced to interact grrfumblezig egoism."

Another example sentence using this term is: "The narrative myths of ancient Chinese culture grrfumblezig collectivism."

A third example sentence using this term is: "Their unconditional commitment to disbelief of all assertions, even in the presence of amply sufficient evidence, grrfumblezig nihilism."

What term could replace grrfumblezig in this sentence, to mean "to realize as a moral norm" or "to bring into being as a moral norm"?

NOTE: This question asks what I intended to ask here:
[What single word (verb) means 'to assert as a moral norm' or 'to support as a moral norm'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381797/what-single-word-verb-means-to-assert-as-a-moral-norm-or-to-support-as-a-mo/381814#381814)

Comment: Now it looks like 'avows' to me.

Comment: You don't need to use a nonsense word like *grrfumblezig* in your questions. The usual convention is to use a bunch of underscores like `__________`

Comment: are you looking for more "accepted the pretense of" or "regarded as a moral truth" ?  Is a "moral norm" looking for "unquestioning obedience to" as if a orthodox ritual, or more like "habituated acceptance" ?

Answer (score 1):

In the sentences you use above (rather than your description of them), I would consider the word:

> ***[venerated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/venerated)***
>   venerated; venerating
>   -- transitive verb
>
> 1
>   :  to regard with reverential respect or with admiring deference
>
> 2
>   :  to honor (as an icon or a relic) with a ritual act of devotion

Comment: I think this word usually refers to honoring a person or thing, not a concept.

Comment: @Barmar while I certainly agree with "usually" I've seen terms like "veneration of technology" .  "moral" and "norm" are in some ways oxy-morons  - unless I hear 'norm' to be something more like 'canon' or 'orthodoxy' . I'm up for different answers though... I think when a group treats a concept reverentially .. (well that shares the root with venerate I assume) ... I'm just offering it as a possibility depending upon exactly what they want to convey.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest "normalised." It doesn't have the specific restriction to a "moral" norm that you ask for, but I think that's too esoteric a construction to have its own specific verb. Normalising has the sense of taking some hitherto abnormal thing and making it normal.

Alternatively, how about words like "promoted" or "encouraged." They don't have the specific meaning you're asking for, but would fit in your example sentences and have the same overall sense.